# Array of Bitmap Arrays in Haxe + OpenFL

Tags: arrays, bitmap, haxe, openfl

I have a set of bitmaps with the 8 stages of an explosion that I can easy put into an array. But I need 40 of those explosion arrays. Is there a simple way to create 40 arrays and put them into one array without having to declare 40 individual explosion arrays first. I'm thinking to cycle through a loop where one array is continually declared as a new array, each time pushing it into the main array, but am new to Haxe + OpenFL.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr:Array<Array<Int>> = [];
var arr2:Array<Int>;
for(i in 0...40)
{
   arr2 = [i];
   arr[i] = arr2;
}
trace(arr);
```

http://try.haxe.org/#6bf16

Comment: Great! So would I not need to create a new instance of each explosion array before adding it/them to the main array?